# Increasing suction force

Tags: robotic-arm, design, valve

I'm trying to increase the suction force of the end effector in a pick and place system. Is it a good idea to add an extra vacuum pump and put it in parallel? AFAIK, having an extra pump in parallel increases airflow whilst an extra pump in series decreases pressure. However, this paper I'm reading claims to have two pumps in parallel: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01439.pdf

> To achieve this result the suction is driven by two vacuum pumps in
>   parallel, each rated with a free air flow rate of 10CFM and an
>   ultimate vacuum pressure of 0.3Pa.

In fact, would adding an extra pump render no effect as the pumps may leak due to such low pressure? The pump I've got is a rather weak one: 12V, vacuum range: 0 - 0.082Mpa, pressure range: -0.12Mpa - 0, flow: 400L/H. It's one of those with a rotating cam inside.